# re-mounting a HDD after grub failed

Tags: linux, hard-drive, grub2, manjaro

I have a SCSI hdd caddy (that replaces my cd drive in my laptp) in my computer that is running manjaro with grub2 as the bootloader and this stack of software refuses to connect or mount the /dev/sdX device.

The output of dmesg |grep SATA is:

```
[    0.415928] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: AHCI 0001.0300 32 slots 2 ports 6 Gbps 0x3 impl SATA mode
[    0.416761] ata1: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xd3318000 port 0xd3318100 irq 47
[    0.416763] ata2: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xd3318000 port 0xd3318180 irq 47
[    0.732593] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[    2.629227] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 310)
```

lsbk(sda is my main ssd not the one in the caddy):

```
sda      8:0    0 232,9G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   300M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0   100M  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0  29,3G  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0  29,3G  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0  58,6G  0 part /
└─sda6   8:6    0   9,8G  0 part [SWAP]
```

As a result of that i tried to pass 'libata.force=2:1.5G' to GRUB2 (by going to advanced  and then pressing 'e' for boot options and appending the  option at the end of the line that starts with 'linux')

Is there perhaps a good way of manually reestablishing the connection between grub2 and the HDD while already booted in?
Is there anything i am missing?